# Building an .msi wipes out the .svn files in the directory and creates subversion conflicts

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn

Using Subversion (TortoiseSVN/CollabNet Edge); building an .msi (Visual Studio Installer project type) wipes out the .svn files in the directory and creates subversion conflicts. TortoiseSVN won't allow the Resolve command. How to resolve the conflicts?

Comment: Version control is used more often for source files only, not generated output (executables etc).  Consider creating a "deployment" folder and configure your project to copy the finished .msi file into it after building.  That way VS won't continually delete it.

Comment: The tool you use should not wipe out the .svn folders, remove them, or change their content. What do you use to create the MSI files?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the parent directory (or move it to a different location) and do an svn update on the parent directory.

Svn can't do anything if the .svn folders are missing. So you have to give svn a chance to recover its own directory structures.

Comment: There are changes in the files that need to be committed. If the parent directory is deleted (or moved), the update will bring in files that don't have the changes which will need to be again updated in Visual Studio creating the same problem.

Comment: It is the Visual Studio process of building the .msi for release which wipes out the files and replaces them with new ones.

Comment: You could copy the files back from the location you made your backup and then do the commit.

Comment: belwood, I agree. But the developer in question is adamant that these files be under source control.

Comment: tangens, we're in the process of seeing if we can make that work.